# Get value from combo selection and display the result to text field using jQuery and Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'd like to display certain record from table according `combo/drop` selection in Laravel. I'm following instructions from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120776/laravel-ajax-jquery-input-value-of-select-dropdown-to-textbox)  but still can not get it to work.

Here is my view code and my jQuery script:

**a. combo box**

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="cde_mesg" id="cmb_mesg" required>
  <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">
    -- PICK MESSAGE-- 
  </option>
  @foreach($message as $messages)
    <option value="{{ $messages->cde_mesg }}">
      {{ $messages->nme_customer }}
    </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

**b. text field**

```
<input type="text" name="ad1_contract" id="ad1_contract" class="form-control">
```

**c. jquery script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cmb_mesg").change(function(){
      var x =  $(this).val();
      $("#ad1_contract").val(x);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Should work fine assuming the `<select>` exists on page load and you aren't duplicating same id elsewhere. Any errors in browser dev tools console?

Comment: how to check the error from firefox?
which menu from dev tool console should i check?

Comment: open the firefox dev tools (F12) and look in console

Comment: no error show from the consoles

Comment: What does `console.log($("#cmb_mesg").length)` show? Should be 1 not zero

Comment: no information showed from the instruction console.log()

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense that this is not working as it is presented... unless there is some dynamic element changing after page load perhaps?  If so, try changing your jQuery ready function to:

```
$("#cmb_mesg").on('change', function(){
      var x =  $(this).val();
      $("#ad1_contract").val(x);
});
```

The benefits of doing the on (delegated) vs change (direct) are well explained in [this answer, with further references to other good explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599923/change-vs-on-change-handler-in-jquery).  You can review further the `.on("change", selector, handler)` there, as well, to see if that makes a difference.